# How do I run a two-way repeated measure MANOVA in R?

Tags: r, time-series, anova, repeated-measures, manova

I am trying to run a repeated measure MANOVA in R, with two within subjects independent variables and three dependent variables.

I converted the df in long format and I am now trying to run the analysis using the RM.MANOVA package. There are no missing values in the data.

```
head(dflong)
  ID IV1      IV2    DV1        DV2         DV3
1  1 BuiltSec OffSec 2.716667   2.504202    2.403361
2  2 BuiltSec OffSec 3.158333   3.134454    3.369748
3  3 BuiltSec OffSec 3.008333   2.361345    2.983193
4  4 BuiltSec OffSec 2.683333   1.865546    2.689076
5  5 BuiltSec OffSec 2.791667   2.798319    2.747899
6  6 BuiltSec OffSec 3.033333   2.680672    3.142857

> str(dflong)
'data.frame':   264 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ ID: Factor w/ 44 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ IV1: Factor w/ 3 levels "BuiltSec","IntervSec",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ IV2: Factor w/ 2 levels "NoffSec","OffSec": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ DV1: num  2.72 3.16 3.01 2.68 2.79 ...
 $ DV2: num  2.5 3.13 2.36 1.87 2.8 ...
 $ DV3: num  2.4 3.37 2.98 2.69 2.75 ...

model.rm <- RM(cbind(dv1, dv2, dv3) ~ IV1*IV2, data = dflong, subject = "ID", no.subf=2)
```

I get a "Error in WTS_out[i, ] <- round(results$WTS, dec) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

It seems like there is some issue with the WTS index calculation, but I do not understand how to solve it.
Do you know what this error means and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The necessary function (multRM) was not available some weeks ago, as I learnt on GitHub
https://github.com/smn74/MANOVA.RM/issues/5

Now it is available and it works!