# Two-way mixed repeated measures MANOVA in Python or R

Tags: r, python, repeated-measures, manova, two-way

I compare three groups:

- A control group
- Two different clinical populations

They are subjected to 6 different types of stimuli, several times each (repeated measures), and 5 dependent variables are collected on each stimulus exposition.

Therefore, I have two independent variables (IV), being the group (between-subject) and the stimulus type (within-subject): this is a mixed design approach. I also have 5 dependent variables (DV): the analysis will be multivariate.

I would like to evaluate the interaction "group" x "stimulus type", and the difference in the groups' performance in general, but also with respect to the different stimulus types (two-way analysis).

This brings me to a two-way mixed repeated measures MANOVA.

I would like to perform this analysis in Python (preferred) or in R, but I might be open to open-source solutions. Can you help me identify:

1. Is this analysis feasible in either Python or R?
2. If so, which package (and function) would be appropriate for this analysis?

I already identified:

- Python's `statsmodels.multivariate.manova`, but comments at the top of the `MANOVA.mv_test()` [method](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/multivariate/manova.html#MANOVA.mv_test) lead me to think this is not for two-way analyses.
- R's [Stats](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/manova.html) package comes with a `manova()` method, but I am having a hard time figuring the assumptions.
- R's [MANOVA.RM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MANOVA.RM/index.html) package, with the `multRM()` method, mentioned [in this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486420/how-do-i-run-a-two-way-repeated-measure-manova-in-r), but I'm not convinced it's appropriate for mixed design yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R's `MANOVA.RM` package provides indeed the `multRM()` method. The `MANOVA.RM` [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MANOVA.RM/MANOVA.RM.pdf) actually mentions between and within-subject variables in page 13, which comforts the fact that the package is indeed appropriate for mixed design.

Python's `rpy2` should allow the use of Python and minimizing the use of R.